# .play .onclick stopped working

Tags: javascript, function

It's been three weeks since I worked on my code, but I'm pretty sure last time I opened it, it worked. Now it doesn't. Either I'm going insane and having false memories (wishful thinking maybe), or something inexplicable has happened.

My code:

```
<div id="Video1" >
    <button onclick="playVid()" type="button">Start conversation</button>
    <br>
    <script> 
        var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo"); 

        function playVid() { 
            myVideo.play(); 
            $.scriptcam.startRecording();
            $( "#recordStopButton" ).attr( "disabled", false );
        }
    </script>

<video id='myVideo' width="640" height="480" controls>

<source src="videos/Anger_He.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

So when they click on the button, it should start playing a video and simultaneously activate the scriptcam recorder.

netbeans debugger : undefined is not a function (.play)
undefined is not a function (onclick)

Any idea what is going on?

edit/ it appears to be a problem in CHrome; How can I get it to work in Chrome?

Comment: Is the code actually defined above the video element?

Comment: Did you try to alert something from the function playVid()? It doesn't seem to be incorrect, you know. Therefore tell us if an alert appears when you write it inside the function. If not you can try to give a class or id to the function, then query it with querySelector or querySelectAll and fire the function from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are mixing your variables and ids. Use `vid.play()` instead of `myVideo`. Even better, move the variable into your function so that you are not relying on global variables and there is no longer any question on variable scope.

```
function playVid() { 
    var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo"); 
    vid.play(); 
    $.scriptcam.startRecording();
    $( "#recordStopButton" ).attr( "disabled", false );
}
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! Very strange, my own code worked in firefox only, but this code works in firefox AND chrome. thank you :)

Comment: it might have worked because ID values map to DOM Elements by default in modern browsers (and IE6+ :P) - strange that didn't work in Chrome et al, it should have.